# Cannot load netstandard2.1 assembly in when adding an analyzer in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, sourcegenerators

Lately I've been interested in writing source generators and at some point I needed to write an `DiagnosticSuppressor` to accommodate some generated logic. As Rider (my IDE of choice) does not support suppressors I needed Visual Studio to test that it is working.

But in process of loading it's NuGet package to VS I encountered a problem, that VS (19/22) can't instantiate a generator object due to inability to load netstandard assembly.

The generators are written using netstandard2.1 and a working in Rider fine just fine (both MacOS & Windows). Is there any solution to enable it in VS?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: That is accurate, VS loads the installed version of the .NETFramework, not .NETCore, which limits you to .NETStandard <= 2.0

Comment: You should target netstandard2.0